# Printing database query response as json array/list in Karate

Tags: json, karate

I am using DBUtils' readRows() method in Karate and receiving a response in the form of a list of maps which I save as a json variable called response. The data looks like this:

```
[
      {
        "ID": "001"
      },
      {
        "ID": "002"
      },
      {
        "ID": "003"
      }
]
```

The assertion works with

```
* match response[*].ID == ["001", "002", "003"]
```

but it doesn't print anything for

```
* print response[*].ID
```

I was expecting it would print the three id's `["001", "002", "003"]`. Any idea why its not printing anything?

Comment: @PeterThomas the answer you gave in my other question didn't help, just like the answer for this question

Comment: this question has nothing to do with DBUtils BTW which confused me. hint: `print` supports only JS. when you see a `*` or `..` it is JsonPath. read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#get

Comment: @mitymouse store the response[*].ID in a variable and print the variable.

Comment: @PeterThomas thanks, that helped. Can you not associate my question as you have done above, since it has nothing to do with that?
@Neodawn thanks for the tip. Actually, I tried that and it didn't work. You have to store it using what Peter mentioned in the link above (github.com/intuit/karate#get). So for the example above, first `* def output = $response[*].ID` and then `* print output`. If you try to print it directly like `* print $response[*].ID` it won't work.

Comment: @mitymouse done. now you know what to do ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
* def output = $response[*].ID
* print output
```